# WITH RECURSIVE with union among the recursive term

Tags: postgresql, cte, recursive

Is it possible to use `WITH RECURSIVE` queries in PostgreSQL where the recursive term is a union of different tables? My usecase is to extract some tuples from a table and some logical rules:

[image: p_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7) \wedge x_6\neq\texttt{NULL} \wedge x_2 \neq\texttt{NULL}\wedge x_5 \neq\texttt{NULL} \Rightarrow p_2(x_2,x_6)]

And I would like to exploit recursive queries having the following syntax:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_name(
    CTE_query_definition -- non-recursive term
    UNION
    CTE_query definion  -- recursive term
) SELECT * FROM cte_name;
```

where `p1` and `p3` can be tuples from different possible types. This means that my non-recursive term will be:

```
SELECT * from TUPLES
```

While the recursive term generates new tuples from our data but does not have to generate tuples that already exist (CTE with `UNION` without `ALL`).

```
SELECT 
       'ex' AS type_event,
       t1.arg2 AS arg1,
       t1.arg6 AS arg2,
       null AS arg3,
       null AS arg4,
       null AS arg5,
       null AS arg6
    FROM cte_name t1
    WHERE t1.type_event = 'Transfering'
      AND t1.arg2 = t2.arg1
      AND t1.arg6 = t2.arg2

UNION ALL 


       'ex' AS type_event,
       t1.arg2 AS arg1,
       t1.arg6 AS arg2,
       null AS arg3,
       null AS arg4,
       null AS arg5,
       null AS arg6
    FROM cte_name t1
    WHERE t1.type_event = 'Replacement'
      AND t1.arg2 = t2.arg1
      AND t1.arg6 = t2.arg2
UNION ALL

       'ex' AS type_event,
       t1.arg2 AS arg1,
       t1.arg1 AS arg2,
       null AS arg3,
       null AS arg4,
       null AS arg5,
       null AS arg6
    FROM cte_name t1
    WHERE t1.type_event = 'ex'
```

By the way, `WITH RECURSIVE` does not allow to express recursive statements where the recursive element is a union of different selects. Is there an efficient solution that does not involve to programmatically implement this in C++/Java/Python, so that all the data "stays" in the database and I do not need to serialize and desirialize the data multiple times?

Example of input data for `TUPLES`:

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| type_event  | arg1 | arg2 | arg3 | arg4 | arg5 | arg6 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ex          | A    | B    | null | null | null | null |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Transfering | A    | B    | C    | D    | E    | F    |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Replacement | G    | H    | I    | J    | K    | L    |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Expected output after the third and final iteration:

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| type_event  | arg1 | arg2 | arg3 | arg4 | arg5 | arg6 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ex          | A    | B    | null | null | null | null |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Transfering | A    | B    | C    | D    | E    | F    |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Replacement | G    | H    | I    | J    | K    | L    |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ex          | B    | F    | null | null | null | null |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ex          | H    | L    | null | null | null | null |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ex          | B    | A    | null | null | null | null |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ex          | F    | B    | null | null | null | null |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ex          | L    | H    | null | null | null | null |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three parts of the desired recursive term select rows from the same CTE, so you can transform them into a single SELECT:

```
SELECT ...
FROM cte_name t1
WHERE (t1.type_event = 'Transfering' AND t1.arg2 = t2.arg1 AND t1.arg6 = t2.arg2)
   OR (t1.type_event = 'Replacement' AND t1.arg2 = t2.arg1 AND t1.arg6 = t2.arg2)
   OR (t1.type_event = 'ex')
```

Reordering the columns can be done with a [CASE expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE):

```
SELECT 'ex' AS type_event,   -- same for all three
       t1.arg2 AS arg1,      -- same for all three
       CASE t1.type_event
         WHEN 'Transfering' THEN t1.arg6
         WHEN 'Replacement' THEN t1.arg6
         WHEN 'ex'          THEN t1.arg1
       END AS arg2,
       ...
```

Comment: Why I didn't come with this solution in the first place. Furthermore, if I have more complicated conditions, I may just use a `Searched CASE` instead of a `Simple CASE`. If I may have multiple join conditions, I may just adopt the maximum number of joins in the FROM caluse (in the most general case, I'm always using the same table cte_name but multiple more times). Thanks!